# Color "Undefined" in Altair graph

Tags: python, vega, vega-lite, altair

I'm using the altair python library to create html files with vega-lite specifications. I'm encountering a problem where color is not being displayed in my plot. Here is the code:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas
data = 'Test.csv' #this contains three columns: Rating, Frequency, and typ, where 'typ' is either E or O.
a = alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('Rating', type = 'ordinal'),
    alt.Y('Frequency',type = 'quantitative'),
    alt.Color('typ', type = 'nominal')
)
a.save('altairtest.html')
```

I get a graph without colors, and the legend comes up as 'typ' but only with blue, and text reading "undefined.

I am currently working locally on a SimpleHttpsServer. Could this be the reason why? For my purposes it is easier this way than using jupyter. Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the first few lines of the Test.csv file? It will be difficult to give any help without that information.

Answer (score 0):

This usually indicates that there is an issue in your data file. I can reproduce your issue with a `Data.csv` file that looks like this:

```
Rating,Frequency, typ
0,1,O
1,2,E
```

Then the resulting chart looks like this:

[image]

Notice the space before `typ` in the header: spaces are important in CSV files: this means your column is named `" typ"` not `"typ"`.

If you remove the space from the header in the CSV file, the same code gives you this:

```
Rating,Frequency,typ
0,1,O
1,2,E
```

[image]

Make certain your fields *exactly* match your data columns, and your chart should work as expected.